# Can you defer the taxes on the gain of the sale on your home by buying another home?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, home-ownership

Consider a (single) home owner who has lived in the home for many years. The home was purchased for $200K and then sold for $600K. That is a $400K capital gain. I understand that the first $250K is not taxed. Can the homeowner defer the tax on the remaining $150K by buying a new home to live in?

I am in the United States.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the homeowner defer the tax on the remaining $150K by buying a new
> home to live in?

That program ended in the 1990s. Before then you could defer taxes on the gains by buying a replacement house. There were limits, but many people used that program.

Based on your example, the gain above 250K would be subject to taxes.

Now you should be able to reduce some the gains somewhat when you take into account the expenses related to sale of the house.

In addition some expenses related to improving the house could be used to increase the basis. You would need proof of the expenses. These would be things like finishing the basement or putting on an addition. It would not be replacing the roof after 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to not sell it and convert it to a rental property.

Then, you can do a [1031 exchange](https://www.doorloop.com/blog/1031-exchange-rules) on the terms you mentioned, according to the rules of that program.

This is a keystone in Robert Allen's philosophy of "never sell". Continue to accumulate rental properties, selling only in a 1031 exchange. Let your estate pay the capital gains tax :)  Equity can be accessed by taking mortgages.